# After all the data successful load from Ajax, then I want to use another ajax to change the image loading.gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(response) {
               for (var i = 0; i < response.posts.length; i++) {
                      post_id = posts[i].id;
                      title = post[i].title
                      thumbnail = posts[i].thumbnail_url;
                      $('#post').append('<p>'+title+'</p>')
                      $('#post').append('<img id="'+post_id+'" src="/loading.gif">)
               }
            }
       })
```

For the image, I want after all the data successful load from Ajax, then I want to use another ajax to change the image loading.gif to the thumbnail_url.
Is there any better way, or anything please kindly help me..!

Answer (score 0):

Just before you call the ajax function, append the #posts with a div with id=latest that had loading.gif image.  Once you receive response from ajax, remove this div from posts.  Then using your function, you can append the posts and images.  I made a few syntax changes to the code.  I could not really check the code.  But I am sure it will work. Hope this helps.

```
    $('#post').append('<div id="latest"><img src="/loading.gif"></div>');        

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response) {
            var posts = response.posts;
            //remove the div with loading gif                
            $( "#latest" ).remove();

            for (var i = 0; i < response.posts.length; i++) {
                  var post_id = posts[i].id;
                  var title = posts[i].title;
                  var thumbnail = posts[i].thumbnail_url;
                  $('#post').append('<p>'+title+'</p>');
                  $('#post').append('<img class="loading" id="'+post_id+'" src="'+thumbnail+'">');  
           }
        }
    });

    <style>
        .loading{
            background:transparent url(loading.gif) center center no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is thumbnail is also the link. I store the image in google storage. All the data from my server are loaded but the image seems slow to load so, I want to add the preloader to it.

Comment: Apply class loading to each image. It puts loading.gif in the background using css.  It will be invisible once the image is loaded. This may pose a problem if the images are transparent. Then you can execute a function after a few seconds, which removes class loading from images.